# How to implement Custom Sink for a Embedded Flume Agent?

Tags: java, flume

I am building a spring boot standalone application that needs to consume messages from a remote server and write them to a `Syslog Server`. I am using Flume embedded agent to reliably log messages. But I am getting following error.

> Caused by: org.apache.flume.FlumeException: Component type of
>   com.security.flume.sink.SyslogSink is not in allowed types of
>   [AVRO]    at
>   org.apache.flume.agent.embedded.EmbeddedAgentConfiguration.checkAllowed(EmbeddedAgentConfiguration.java:308)
>   ~[flume-ng-embedded-agent-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]    at
>   org.apache.flume.agent.embedded.EmbeddedAgentConfiguration.validate(EmbeddedAgentConfiguration.java:182)
>   ~[flume-ng-embedded-agent-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]    at
>   org.apache.flume.agent.embedded.EmbeddedAgentConfiguration.configure(EmbeddedAgentConfiguration.java:199)
>   ~[flume-ng-embedded-agent-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]    at
>   org.apache.flume.agent.embedded.EmbeddedAgent.doConfigure(EmbeddedAgent.java:151)
>   ~[flume-ng-embedded-agent-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]    at
>   org.apache.flume.agent.embedded.EmbeddedAgent.configure(EmbeddedAgent.java:98)
>   ~[flume-ng-embedded-agent-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]

**As per the documentation `Embedded Agent` only supports `Avro Sink`. Does it mean we can not even write a custom sink?**

I am fairly new to Flume. I really appreciate your help on this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this means that for embedded agent you just can use `AvroSink` as a custom sink. However, there are some techniques you can use to collect data from an external source using custom components:

- Create a custom client that is capable of establishing communication with Flume source that exists in prior, like `AvroSources` or `SyslogTcpSource`.
- Create a custom flume source having direct communication with a preexisting client through an IPC or RPC protocol.

I hope this answer is not too late and can help you with something. Thanks for Reading!!